# Why is the conditional statement in my regex pattern getting rid of other matches when it shouldn't change anything?

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements, match

Here is my text (it will be looking through other text as well, but this is what I am having trouble with):

```
<a href="/wiki/Basketball" title="Basketball">basketball</a>, the 

<li class="interwiki-cs"><a href="//cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/" title="" lang="cs" hreflang="cs">esky</a><

<li class="interwiki-da"><a href="//da.wikipedia.org/wiki/" title="" lang="da" hreflang="da"><b>Dansk</b></a></li>
```

I'm trying to get 3 matches where 2 groups (separated by a semicolon) are:

```
/wiki/Basketball;basketball
//cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/;esky
//da.wikipedia.org/wiki/;Dansk
```

With this pattern: `(?<=<a href=")(.*?)".*?>([\w\s\./,0-9]*?)<`, I can match the first two correctly. To try to also get the last match, I added in a conditional to check for the `<b>`: `(?<=<a href=")(.*?)".*?>(<?)(?(2)b>)([\w\s\./,0-9]*?)<`. This gets the last match correctly, but now the first two don't match.

Can you please explain why this happens and what the correct way to do this is?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)?

Comment: Can't you use `(?<=<a href=")(.*?)".*?>(.*?)(?=</a>)`?

Comment: @Ray that would get <b>Dansk</b> instead of just Dansk

Comment: @sudden_appearance Yes, because I am trying to get better at regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest i have trouble understanding 'conditional' myself. I asked question about it, but didn't get an answer.

I took advantage of `[^]` and did this:

```
re.findall('(?<=<a href=")(.*?)".*>([^>]+)<',string)
```

or

```
re.findall('(?<=<a href=")(.*?)".*(?<=>)([^>]+)(?=<)',string)
```

In both cases the second group matches a non-empty string that follows '>', do not contain '>' and preceds '<'. It should match the last non_empty string between tags.

By addind '?' to the '.' after the first group, the second group should match the first non_empty string between tags:

```
re.findall('(?<=<a href=")(.*?)".*?(?<=>)([^>]+)(?=<)',string)
```

Separately, the following snippet should catch all non-empty strings between tags:

```
re.findall('(?<=>)([^>]+)(?=<)',string)
```

I hope I'm not wrong, but if that's the case, please tell me.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting, I wouldn't have thought to do that. Is the difference between using the lookahead/behind vs matching the literal characters just whether it is included in group 0 or not?

Comment: If you are looking only for groups, using `re.search.groups()` or 're.findall`, than there is no difference. Or so i think... (P.S. When there are groups in the regex, `re.findall' will return only them.)